# design of directory, fileupload and image handling class

Tags: php, architecture, software-design

I'm implementing a **file upload, Directory** and **Imageupload** class in php. What I have planned  to implement in **Directory class**, are the following functions such as:

1. Retrieve list of files, folder in a directory
2. Create folder, search recursively in a directory `{path}`

In **FileHandling.class.php** following methods such as:

1. whether file exists in a directory, . c
2. check file extension of file uploading
3. Handling moving files from a location to another
4. Renaming a file

**In imageUpload.class.php**  functions such as:

1. resizing image,
2. creating watermark.

What I would like to know , where should the function exist, should I have only one `fileHandling.class.php` and it includes method of `Directory.class.php`, or keep them separate.

Should `ImageUpload.class.php` be composition of `fileUpload.class.php`? And what particular software pattern can I apply here such as Facade, Singleton etc.

Comment: Why did you add the 'uml' tag?

Comment: removed it :) any comment on the question :)

Comment: Apologies, I'm not the php guy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should confine all FileSystem operations to one Factory. Use the Factory pattern to compartmentalize Uploads, File Listing etc